# Powershell - revert parameter to default value?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I ran a command using the Active Directory Module for Windows Powershell:

```
Set-ADServiceAccount -Identity testAccount -PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount testGroup
```

I actually don't want `testGroup` to be the `PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount` anymore.

Is there a way of reverting things in PowerShell? I want to set `PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount` back to whatever default value it was?

[image: command syntax screenshot]

Comment: That very much depends on the implementation of the CmdLet. What module is that function from?

Comment: @gvee It is from the Active Directory Module for Windows Powershell

Comment: I might be being thick here; but I don't see the parameter you're talking about in the documentation: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617252.aspx

Comment: @gvee interesting, it's not listed in that documentation, but its definitely in the powershell help documentation. I've edited my post with a screenshot

Comment: There's no automatic way to revert setting changes without you having recorded their previous value in a variable first. Did you store the output of  `Get-ADServiceAccount -Identity testAccount` anywhere before you made the change? Otherwise you could Google to see if there is a default value and change it back to that (my guess would be default is `$null` but it is a guess).

Comment: @MarkWragg I did not store the output of that command anywhere prior to running my command. Thank you for suggesting the $null parameter though.